# Acumatica conditional update - Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'

Tags: acumatica

We have written code to update Base Price on the non-stock item maintenance window when the MSRP field is changed with the following code:

```
protected void InventoryItem_RecPrice_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXCommandPreparingEventArgs e)
{

  var row = (InventoryItem)e.Row;
  InventoryItemExt itemExt = row.GetExtension<InventoryItemExt>();


  INPriceClass itemPriceClass = PXSelect<INPriceClass, Where<INPriceClass.priceClassID, Equal<Current<InventoryItem.priceClassID>>>>.Select(Base);
  INPriceClassExt priceClassExt = row.GetExtension<INPriceClassExt>();

  //FIXED, MSRP PLUS, MSRP PERCENTAGE

  if (priceClassExt.UsrPricingCategoryID = "FIXED")
  {

  cache.SetValue<InventoryItem.basePrice>(row, row.RecPrice + priceClassExt.UsrPricingFixedAmount);
  }

}
```

However, we get the following error:

\App_RuntimeCode\NonStockItemMaint.cs(49): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'
\App_RuntimeCode\NonStockItemMaint.cs(49): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'bool'
Compiler time, in seconds: 6.0001164

Comment: The line causing the issue is the line that contains:   if (priceClassExt.UsrPricingCategoryID = "FIXED")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens because you are using the assignment operator (=) instead of the equality operator (==). To fix, simply change the if statement to:

```
if (priceClassExt.UsrPricingCategoryID == "FIXED")
```

Comment: It validated and published.  Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, I now get an error when I open the non-stock maintenance window...

Comment: Invalid argument type in the event handler PX.Objects.IN.NonStockItemMaint_Extension::InventoryItem_RecPrice_FieldUpdated

Comment: Can you find out which line is throwing the exception? Going to help->Trace might provide some cues.

Comment: The signature of your FieldUpdated event is using CommandPreparingEventArgs instead of FieldUpdatedEventArgs

Comment: 1/8/2018 12:00:39 PM Warning: 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 

   at PX.Objects.IN.NonStockItemMaint_Extension.InventoryItem_RecPrice_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e) 
   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnFieldUpdated(String name, Object row, Object oldValue, Boolean externalCall) 
   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.a(TNode A_0, TNode A_1, IDictionary A_2, PXCacheOperation A_3, Boolean A_4)

Comment: I set the CommitChanges to true on the RecPrice field so I expected it to update the Default Price value as soon as I changed the RecPrice (MSRP).  However, I dont get the error until I attempt to save the item.

Comment: Figured it out.  It doesn't change immediately but it does on the Save action.